# Making two fields compound index in mongoDb and update the document

Tags: mongodb, compound-index

I'm using mongoDb in our project and got stuck at a point.
I'm using bulkOperation of mongoDb to save a list of Objects.
I need to make two fields **(mac and gatewaytime )** as a compound index on a collection that make up an unique combination for documents in collection.

I wanted to update the whole document if any combination of mac and gatewaytime found with a the new document.

This scenario is similer to the _id index created with each document. Just the difference is that here I need to make a compound index of these two fields.

I found that we can make an compund index as **Unique** but this just reject any document if found to be duplicate. I need this duplicate document to be updated with the new document in my case.

If question is not undestandable, please let me know freely.

Comment: Is it not very clear what you want to achieve. As I understood you have a data already in collection and now you want to create unique index and MongoDB refuses to do that because of duplicates. Now you want to deduplicate your data. Your question is how to do that in bulk update, or what? Or I didn't get it?

Comment: No, Actully yes I have data already in collection. and also I'm able to create compund index (mac and gatewaytime) . Now when I do BulkOperation to insert list of data into collection. Now if any data is found to be present in collection duplicating any data that I'm inserting with same mac and gatewaytime , I want existin document  to be updated  with the new document.

Traditionaly if duplicate document is found during insertion, mongodb throws **duplicate key error** and reject the new document. Instead of rejecting this I want the existing document to be updated